# mobx-react-form textfield default value not recognized on submit

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mobx, mobx-react-form

The code is as follows

```
 <TextField {...form.$("phone.countryCode").bind()} value={222} />
```

The form setup is as follows

```
{
        name: "phone",
        fields: [
          {
            name: "countryCode",
            label: "Country Code:",
            bindings: "TextField",
            placeholder: "+",
            rules: "required",
          }
       ]
}
```

The value displays correctly in the textfield. But when i submit the form, it shows "required" error.

I assume **field.input.onChange** is not triggered when we set the value like this and hence the mobx field is not updated with the value.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Edit:

The value is a dynamic one based on the country selection. So you cannot set the value during initialise. That is why i had to go for this approach.

Comment: 222 is just a sample value. The question is if you are storing a value in a text field(or may be a hidden field) why it doesn't update the form? (Also regarding the upvotes, may be there are people who faced similar issue)

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to override `value` on the `TextField`, mobx-react-form (I am assuming you are using it) can't possibly know that you are doing it. Just pass default value while initialising the form, like so:

```
const fields = [
  {
    name: "countryCode",
    label: "Country Code:",
    bindings: "TextField",
    placeholder: "+",
    rules: "required",
    value: 'YOUR_DEFAULT_VALUE_HERE'
  }
]

new MobxReactForm({ fields });
```

If the value depends on the other value then you can use `useEffect`, for example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // set countryCode value manually with needed value
  FormModel.$("countryCode").set(country.code);
// Add needed deps
}, [country])
```

Comment: The value is a dynamic one based on the country selection. So you cannot set the value during initialise. That is why i had to go for the approach mentioned in the post.

Comment: Add this info to the question then? I'll update the answer with dynamic approach

Comment: Added the necessary details

Comment: So have my answer helped you? Do you have any additional questions?